# SFDX auth:web:login to SAML org redirects to SF Login form

Tags: salesforcedx, saml

Our sandbox is set for SSO SAML. I can directly access the org via SSO and not have to enter a username or password.

When trying to login using sfdx force:auth:web:login I am presented with the SF Login form instead of being automatically authenticated to the sandbox. I have used '-r https://test.salesforce.com' as well as using the My Domain name. Prior to the sfdx command, I have authenticated to the sandbox so it knows what the username is.

I have run sfdx update, changed by default browser to Microsoft Edge, cleared my browser cache, etc. What could I be missing so that I can be automatically authorized instead of being redirected the the Login form?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has run into this, the solution in my case was to Enable Lightning Login.